# How to change data attribute of adjacent td in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a code like this with two td columns , if i click on the fa icon

```
<i class="fa pad5 fa-unlock-alt" ></i>
```

then i need to change the `data-invoice-lock="0"`.
i tried this

```
$(this).closest('td').find('.invoiceCostCol').attr('data-invoice-lock','0');
```

but not getting the result

INPUT

```
<td rowspan="1" class="reportSmallWd invoiceCostCol" data-invoice-lock="1"></td>  
<td rowspan="1" class="reportSmallWd"> 
    <i class="fa pad5 fa-unlock-alt" ></i>
</td>
```

The OUTPUT required

```
<td rowspan="1" class="reportSmallWd invoiceCostCol" data-invoice-lock="0"></td>     
<td rowspan="1" class="reportSmallWd"> 
    <i class="fa pad5 fa-unlock-alt" ></i>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest of target `td` is `tr`. You should change `closest('td')` to `closest('tr')`. The code should changed to

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.invoiceCostCol').attr('data-invoice-lock','0');
```

Or use

```
$(this).parent().prev().attr('data-invoice-lock','0');
```

If structure of your html is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $(this).closest('tr').find('.invoiceCostCol').removeAttr('data-invoice-lock').attr('data-invoice-lock','0');
```

Answer (score 1):

Well in general you need to find the closest `tr` and then find your element within this `tr`.

However I wrote this additional answer to call your attention to the `data()` method in jQuery. With this method you can manipulate data attributes in your elements like setting and getting values. Why is this often times "*better*" than using `attr()` or `prop()`?

**Short answer:**

Using **data()** you can return a `JavaScript object` that can contain lots of `keys` and `values` and it is much easier to process. However when you use `data()` instead of `attr()` you won't actually see the change of a value in your browser inspector. But just use `console.log()` to show the actual value and you'll see it is changes.

The fiddle below features both methods for testing, however `attr()` is commented out at the moment. Just play with it and see how it works.

**Here you go with the working fiddle:**

```js
$(function(){

$('i.fa-unlock-alt').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td.invoiceCostCol').data('invoice-lock','0');
  //$(this).closest('tr').find('td.invoiceCostCol').attr('data-invoice-lock','0');
  console.log($('td.invoiceCostCol').data('invoice-lock'));
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table>
<tr>


<td rowspan="1" class="reportSmallWd invoiceCostCol" data-invoice-lock="1">

</td>

<td rowspan="1" class="reportSmallWd"> 
  <i class="fa pad5 fa-unlock-alt" ></i>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also user [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) in place of `attr` :

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.invoiceCostCol').data('invoice-lock', '0');
```

**Here is working example:**

```js
$('.pad5').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.invoiceCostCol').data('invoice-lock', '0');
  alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.invoiceCostCol').data('invoice-lock'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1" class="reportSmallWd invoiceCostCol" data-invoice-lock="1">

    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" class="reportSmallWd">
      <i class="fa pad5 fa-unlock-alt"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```